# Percorrer uma lista obtendo o elemento atual e o próximo

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

Como posso implementar dois `for(Teste teste : lista) {}` para percorrer uma mesma lista? Sendo que, o segundo `foreach` teria que sempre olhar o próximo item desta lista?

Tentei dessa forma mas ele sempre compara o mesmo objeto.

```
for (Object object : listaLinhas) {
    for (Object object2 : listaLinhas) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar um `if (object != object2)`

Comment: @NatanFernandes E se puder ter elementos repetidos na lista?

Comment: exatamente, eu gostaria de fazer dois `foreach` justamente para verificar se existem itens repetidos dentro de um `List<E>`

Comment: João, para verificar se há itens repetidos, um jeito melhor é criar um `Set` (que não permite elementos repetidos) e ver se o tamanho é igual ao da lista: `Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>(lista);  if (set.size() == lista.size()) {  System.out.println("Não há elementos repetidos");  } else { System.out.println("Há elementos repetidos");  }`

Comment: E para saber **quais** se repetem (não somente se tem ou não): https://stackoverflow.com/q/7414667

Comment: Sim, tentei fazer isso para verificar se um atributo Id se repetia em uma lista de objetos. Utilizei `!set.add(obj.getId())` para verificar se esse item já está nesse hashSet. Porém, ele se repete de forma não linear, em momentos aleatórios na lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa fazer um `for` dentro do outro. Basta fazer um único *loop*, só que usando os índices. Aí você vai do primeiro até o penúltimo, e para obter o próximo, basta pegar o índice seguinte:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size() - 1; i++) {
    Object atual = lista.get(i);
    Object proximo = lista.get(i + 1);
    // usa o atual e proximo
    // ...
}
```

---

Outra opção é obter o `Iterator` da lista e ir pegando os elementos dele, um a um:

```
Iterator<Object> it = lista.iterator();
Object atual = it.next(); // pega o primeiro
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object proximo = it.next(); // pega o próximo

    // usa o atual e proximo
    // ...

    // atualiza o atual
    atual = proximo;
}
```

Ou ainda, o mesmo algoritmo, mas usando os índices:

```
Object atual = lista.get(0); // pega o primeiro
for (int i = 1; i < lista.size(); i++) { // for começa do segundo elemento
    Object proximo = lista.get(i); // pega o próximo

    // usa o atual e proximo
    // ...

    // atualiza o atual
    atual = proximo;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, imaginei que dois `foreach` não seriam necessários